# How to copy the data from a running private network to another

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, network

I have two seperately running private ethereum networks,i want to copy the data from the first private network to the second one **without stopping**.I have tried multiple ways but was not successful.I will appreciate if someone can provide some guidance or hint on the best approach here.

Comment: One solution is to add one as a peer of the other and let they sync.

Comment: When you say "two separately running private ethereum networks" you mean two different nodes for the same blockchain? Or two separate blockchains? Being the former, it is possible to connect nodes to each other and let them sync. Check this out: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network